# How can I setup linux to compile FORTRAN code into windows binaries?

Tags: windows, linux, mingw, fortran, cross-compiling

I'm working on a FORTRAN project and I would like to build all of the binaries that I want to maintain on a linux machine that is dedicated for automated builds. I have successfully used **mingw** to build 32-bit and 64-bit binaries from C source for windows machines on the linux machine with the following packages on Ubuntu.

```
apt-get install mingw32
apt-get install mingw-w64
```

Then I run the following commands to actually compile:

```
gcc -b amd64-mingw32msvc -V 4.4.4 -o <...other options>
```

However, the **mingw** packages that I've obtained via apt-get do not include FORTRAN compilers.

Anybody got any ideas on what I can do?

Comment: Just to see if I'm clear - you want to make a windows binary on a linux machine. Right? Since you cannot run (to check whether everything is okey) a win exe on a *nix machine, what is the purpose of something like that?

Comment: @Rook: Presumably the OP has his/her development environment setup on Linux, is familiar with the Linux tools etc. Whether this is enough to compensate for the troubles with cross-compiling vs. compiling natively for Windows e.g. in a virtual machine is another topic.

Comment: @Rook: I'm using an automated build system (on a dedicated machine) and would like to cross-compile for the purpose of keeping the build process all on the same machine (rather than trying to delegate to other dedicated physical or virtual machines). I've edited my post to reflect this info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always download and install a prebuilt compiler from the MinGW(-w64) project itself:

Windows 64-bit: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/4.6.2-1/
Windows 32-bit: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/4.6.2-1/

Just unpack somewhere and add the `cross*/bin` directory to PATH.

I include (obj)c(++) and fortran.

Comment: I ended up downloading one of the automated builds from http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Automated%20Builds/. Specifically, I downloaded mingw-w64-1.0-bin_x86_64-linux_20110808.tar.bz2 for 64-bit support. I will also get the 32-bit version. But this solution works for me, thanks! I wish there was a nice Debian package though...

Comment: Captain: Note that package contains a generic build with no Graphite loop optimization support, and (I think) GCC 4.5. Why not send a feature request to the package maintainer?

Answer (score 3):

if you got mingw32 and the Gnu C cross compiler is working for you ... when why not just get the Gnu Fortran cross compiler, too?

http://www.nber.org/sys-admin/mingw32-fortran-fedora.html

```
EXAMPLE apt-get install mingw32-gcc-fortran
```

Comment: Because Debian doesn't provide packages for that.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread but a few things seem to have changed and people might still be interested in the topic.

Problem: I want to use my linux machine to compile some code and create a .exe that I can send to people using Windows.

Solution: Essentially here: http ://mxe.cc/

What I did:

- Check to see if your system has all the software you need [here](http://mxe.cc/#requirements-debian)
- run

`git clone -b stable https://github.com/mxe/mxe.git`

It will download a few small things and create the directory "mxe" (probably in your home folder)

- cd into that mxe directory and run "make". HOWEVER: this would take hours and take up a few GB on your hard drive so instead run something like

  `make mpfr eigen opencsg cgal qt`

For more ideas on how to shorten that all see [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Cross-compiling_for_Windows_on_Linux_or_Mac_OS_X) or the mxe tutorial or somewhere else ;)

- The easiest way to compile stuff then seems to be something like:

  `~/mxe/usr/bin/i686-pc-mingw32-gfortran -c main.f95`

  `~/mxe/usr/bin/i686-pc-mingw32-gfortran main.o -o outfile.exe`

Of course you can chose something other than fortran, just consult the mxe/usr/bin to see what its called.

Comment: unlike forums, stackoverflow does not have threads, just questions and answers

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 18.04 I use

```
apt install gfortran-mingw-w64
```

Then use the compiler `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gfortran` in place of `gfortran`.  If you're using cmake, you can configure the compiler from the build directory like so:

```
FC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gfortran cmake ..
```