# Fortran cross compilation (Linux to Windows) recent developments

Tags: fortran, cross-compiling

I want to use Linux to compile code and create a .exe that can be used on Windows. The reasons being that I have been having difficulty getting [CGAL](https://www.cgal.org/) to work with MinGW on Windows 7 and this proved trivial using Ubuntu on VirtualBox.

A three year old question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019655/how-can-i-setup-linux-to-compile-fortran-code-into-windows-binaries) advises the download and install of a prebuilt compiler from the MinGW(-w64) project itself. A more recent answer (2 years old) advises the use of http://mxe.cc/. Have there been more recent development for cross compiling fortran programs in Linux for use in Windows or are the answers given previously still the most up to date?

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to compile CGAL with Visual Studio and still call it from Fortran? (Maybe not, I don't know.)

Comment: I would either use the prebuilt binaries or compile the mingw cross compile environment myself.  If you aren't familiar with cross-compile environments there will be a bit of a learning curve.

Comment: It is possible to compile CGAL with Visual Studio as detailed [here](http://www.cgal.org/windows_installation.html) but I do not know how to get it to work with Fortran. I tried taking the C++ headers and putting them in the MinGW "include" folder but this didn't work. 

So the pre-built binaries sound like the way forward.